# Can't get facebook checkins, data array always empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-checkins

I have a strange behavior when trying to get the checkins of a place or user: the result is always an empty data array:

```
{
    "data": [
    ]
}
```

This happens when I use the Graph Explorer: `/4/checkins`

or when I use FQL: `SELECT checkin_id, author_uid, page_id, timestamp from checkin where page_id = 111856692159256`

or when using javascript:

```
FB.api("/me/checkins", function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

I always use an access_token, even ones with ALL permissions available. Simply no result.
I read, that checkins are now post with locations, so I tried `/4/posts?with=location`, but still no luck. Is there some kind of bug, or restriction (country/app-permissions) I am missing?

EDIT: I now got lucky and can get of SOME of my friends their checkins. It's like a 50/50 chance...

Comment: Why are you using `4` at the chegkins url? Are you tried to use `/me/checkins`?

Comment: Number 4 is Mr. Zuckerberg. I checked that he has public checkins to veryfiy that I have a global user, that is available to everyone at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 differences commands, one command is the url to get the user checkins:

- `/me/checkins` will return all checkins of the current user (the user that generate the token)
- `/<USERID>/checkins` will return all checking from the `User ID` that the current user can see.
- `/<PLACEID>/checkins` will return all friends of the current user that made checkin at this place

So, probably you have no friends that made checkins at the id `111856692159256`

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I didn't no about the third one. But as I mentioned: `/me/checkins` is empty, olthough I do have checkins in my profile... And everyone can see some checkins from Mr. Zuckerberg but not my request to the api graph with his ID. I am expecting to see at least this data...

Comment: Try debug your token, you may have made a mistake when generating it. Check the user, application, permissions, etc... The `/me/checkins` is ok for me, it is showing everething correct...

Comment: I debugged my token. It was all right. I even had one token with all permissions. None missing! Still empty. But it's good to know, that it works with you, so the bug is not with facebook.