# Getting facebook friends checkin in list

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on the Integration of facebook sdk with android, i willing to display the all my friends checkins in ListAdapter,Is it possible? i gone through this link it says particular user (or) particular place can be retrieved from this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718623/cant-get-facebook-checkins-data-array-always-empty?rq=1).

Comment: The Facebook Graph API has changed, please go through the latest Documentation. I think you will be able to retrieve only those friends who also use your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Graph API v2.0, you can't retrieve friends data anymore, because all `friends_*` permissions have been removed. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions